# Get variable from returned array

Tags: javascript, arrays

A very simple question I just can't find an answer to:

I have a callback function that returns an array:

```
function(data){
console.log(data);
}
```

Returns:

```
[Object]
    0: Object
        created: 1343816682
        created_userid: "12"
        id: "72"
        status: "Live"
```

I need to pull the returned "id" and set it as a variable. Normally I'd handle this as:

```
var id = (data.id);
```

But this isn't working, presumably as the returned array is a different structure to what I usually handle.

Can some bright spark help me out by showing me the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think perhaps you want `data[0].id` ?

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds.  +1

Comment: @DavidHoerster nimble fingers ;)

Comment: Don't rub it in....  :)